# Need help removing white background when saving DICOM image with transparency

Tags: matlab-figure

This is how my image looks like after I save it:

[image]

I used this following code to process my dicom image in MATLAB, where I added transparency 100% in the pixels that I do not want to see in the image:

The problem I have is when I save the `*.png` file, it saves with a white background which I don't want. Is there any way to remove this white background?

The following is the Matlab code:

```
% Clear the workspace and command window
clc;
clear;

% Specify the file paths for the DICOM images
filePaths = {
    'C:\Users\Chekmenev Lab\Dropbox\Next Energy Image processing\Propane Lung MRI Images\HP propane Pig Lung Imaging\DCOM files\05262023 Dicom\27\S0000319\SE004093\I0000010.dcm',
    'C:\Users\Chekmenev Lab\Dropbox\Next Energy Image processing\Propane Lung MRI Images\HP propane Pig Lung Imaging\DCOM files\05262023 Dicom\27\S0000319\SE004093\I0000014.dcm',
};

% Read the DICOM images
image1 = dicomread(filePaths{1});
image2 = dicomread(filePaths{2});

% Compute the subtraction image
subtracted_image = double(image1) - double(image2);

% Resize the image to 256x256
subtracted_image = imresize(subtracted_image, [256, 256]);

% Set the threshold values
threshold1 = 250; % Adjust the threshold as needed
threshold2 = 760;

% Set the values outside the desired range to NaN
subtracted_image(subtracted_image < threshold1 | subtracted_image > threshold2) = NaN;

% Create a binary mask for the pixels below the threshold
mask = subtracted_image < threshold1;

%mask = subtracted_image < threshold1;

% Create a binary mask for the pixels above the threshold
mask2 = subtracted_image > threshold2;

% Create a new figure
figure;

% Display the image with colormap and transparency
h = imshow(subtracted_image, []);
colormap(jet);

% Create a new colormap with white for 100% transparency
cmap = jet(255);

% Apply the new colormap
colormap(cmap);

% Set the transparency values for the pixels below and above the threshold
alpha_data = ones(size(subtracted_image));

% Set transparency to 0 for pixels below the threshold
alpha_data(mask) = 0;

% Set transparency to 0 for pixels above the threshold
alpha_data(mask2) = 0;

% Set transparency to 0 for NaN values
alpha_data(isnan(subtracted_image)) = 0;

% Set the transparency (AlphaData) of the image
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha_data);

% Set the figure size to 256x256 pixels
set(gcf, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [100 100 256 256]);

% Remove extra space around the image
set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

% Add colorbar
c = colorbar('Location', 'eastoutside');

% Adjust the position of the colorbar
c.Position = [0.95 0.1 0.03 0.8];

% Remove the title
title('');

% Save the figure as a PNG file with a 256x256 resolution
saveas(gcf, 'HP subtraction.png', 'png');
```

Comment: Can you also include your image files to check the source code. Or can it be checked with any image?

Comment: it should work with any .dicom image.